# How to programmatically dismiss system dialogs like "<App> would like to access your photos"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dialog

Is there a way to programmatically dismiss dialogs like the ones where the app wants to access photos, access contacts and access location?

I think there's a way by swizzling API methods, but I don't really know which.  What is the methodology to find out which methods need to be swizzled?  If swizzling is not the way then what could be another alternative?

As a note, this is not for a product, is just for testing so swizzling is a good option if it works.

Comment: I don't think you can pop up system dialog box. They are shown when you try to access and API which is not enabled in settings.

Comment: You know this would never fly in an app store app, right?

Comment: yes, I know.  That's why I added as a note, is not for release.  Just testing purposes.

Comment: I know for the location dialog you can swizzle CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation method to do nothing and this will avoid the dialog.  I don't know about Photos or AddressBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Overriding "access to contacts" dialog

Type this code in your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation (importing `<AddressBook/AddressBook.h>` is necessary:

```
ABAuthorizationStatus ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus(void) {
  return kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
}
```

### 2. Create a swizzling method:

Type in the following method in your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation, or wherever you need it, a helper class would be best. (importing `<objc/runtime.h>` is required:

```
- (void)swizzleSelector:(SEL)selector fromInstancesOfClass:(Class)clazz withBlock:(id)block {
  id replaceBlock = Block_copy(block);
  Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(clazz, selector);
  IMP origImpl = method_getImplementation(origMethod);
  IMP replaceImpl = imp_implementationWithBlock(replaceBlock);
  method_setImplementation(origMethod, replaceImpl);
}

- (void)swizzleSelector:(SEL)selector fromClass:(Class)clazz withBlock:(id)block {
  id replaceBlock = Block_copy(block);
  Method origMethod = class_getClassMethod(clazz, selector);
  IMP origImpl = method_getImplementation(origMethod);
  IMP replaceImpl = imp_implementationWithBlock(replaceBlock);
  method_setImplementation(origMethod, replaceImpl);
}
```

### 3. Overriding "access to location" dialog:

Do the following in your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation. (importing `<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` is required):

```
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation) fromInstancesOfClass:[CLLocationManager class] withBlock:^{}];
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) fromInstancesOfClass:[CLLocationManager class] withBlock:^{}];
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled) fromClass:[CLLocationManager class] withBlock:^{ return NO; }];
```

### 4. Overriding "access to photos" dialog:

Do the following in your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation. (importing `<AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` is required):

```
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(authorizationStatus) fromClass:[ALAssetsLibrary class] withBlock:^{ return ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized; }];
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:) fromInstancesOfClass:[ALAssetsLibrary class] withBlock:^{}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access an alert from anywhere in your app like this. This works for regular alerts but I have not tried it with system alerts (It is possible they don't sit in the same hierarchy as regular alerts, in which case you can't get to them at all). If it does work and you try to release an app with this, it will almost certainly get rejected.

```
for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
{
    for (NSObject* o in w.subviews)
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
        {
            // as an example, this will just dismiss/cancel the alert
            [(UIAlertView*)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
        }
}
```

Comment: As these dialogs mentioned in this question aren't app dialogs but OS specific dialogs this code won't work.